# Calculate data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

| DeviceId | Time | kWh | kW | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13:00 | 10 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 14: 00 | 12 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 15:00 | 13 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 16:00 | 15 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 17:00 | 18 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 18:00 | 15 | 4 | 1 |

I want to use SQL Server to calculate:

| DeviceId | kWh | kW | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (Last row of kWh - first row of kWh) WHERE DeviceId = 1 | SUM of colmun kW WHERE DeviceId = 1 | AVG of colmun A WHERE DeviceId = 1 |
| 2 | (Last row of kWh - first row of kWh) WHERE DeviceId = 2 | SUM of colmun kW WHERE DeviceId = 2 | AVG of colmun A WHERE DeviceId = 2 |

Please help me the SQL!

The expecting result is

| DeviceId | kWh | kW | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 9 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 | 4 |

Comment: Have you tried [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql#group-by-column-expression--n-)? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: I dont know how to calculate:
(Last row of kWh - first row of kWh) WHERE DeviceId = n

Comment: "Last" and "first" as ordered by Time for a DeviceId? Is this strictly ascending as in the sample data?

Comment: Yes. ordered by Time for a DeviceId

Comment: @David; If you want to do it based on first row and last row (Ascending order of time) we can do it using `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to identify the first and last rows in each group using window functions. Then you simply group them up and use conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  d.DeviceId,
  kWh = MAX(CASE WHEN d.isLast = 1 THEN d.kWh END) - MAX(CASE WHEN d.rn = 1 THEN d.kWh END),
  kW = SUM(d.Kw),
  A = AVG(d.A * 1.0)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DeviceId ORDER BY d.Time),
      isLast = ISNULL(LEAD(0) OVER (PARTITION BY d.DeviceId ORDER BY d.Time), 1)
    FROM Data d
) d
GROUP BY
  d.DeviceId;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/L5sZ5eId)

I must say, I'm not an electrical engineer but these calculations do look suspect.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using GROUP BY and [AGGREGATE Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) as in this [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/rEoiIgog).

```
SELECT DeviceId, 
    MAX(kWh) - MIN(kWh) AS kWh, 
    SUM(kW) AS kW, 
    AVG(A) AS A
FROM table_name
GROUP BY DeviceId;
```

This shall give you expected output as :

| DeviceId | kWh | kW | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 9 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 | 4 |

Comment: I dont want to use MAX() and MIN(). I want to use the value of last row and first row. Please help me again!

Comment: `MAX` and `MIN` would do the same. For kWh your `MAX`imum value is in last row and `MIN`imum value in first row.

OR,
Is it always you want `to use the value of last row and first row` ?

Then I can change the query